# flicker issue but don't want to use CLIPCHILDREN style

Tags: c, winapi, static, flicker, editbox

I have a toolbar, on which there are some static child control which display text (e.g: "Find"... ).
There are 2 edit control on this toolrbar. When I resize the main window, I got flicker on some part of the toolbar. So I tried to use `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for the toolbar, and it solves the flikcer issue.

But I don't want to use `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for the following reason:

My toolbar has a beautiful background (using REBARCLASSNAME). So I don't want to the (not good looking) background of the static control appear. Hence in the wndproc of toolbar, I have the following code:

```
if (WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC == message) {
    HWND hStatic = (HWND)lParam;

    if (......)
    {
        SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
        SelectBrush((HDC)wParam, GetStockBrush(NULL_BRUSH));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hence the static display text content with the same background as the toolbar. If I use `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`, this effect don't work anymore.

I also tried to use a background bitmap and set the static control to `SS_BITMAP`, but the function `SetText` doesn't work anymore.

So here is the question:

```
Is there anyway to specify a control that would not be affected by the painting of the parent.  
In my case, the specific control is edit control. But for the static control, I want the parent 
to take the control.

Or how to fix the flicker issue in another way? I tried to double buffer the toolrbar, but it 
doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use null brush, just subclass the static control and draw the background yourself(use toolbar background).